# What's a polite way to say I will not be working?

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language

I want to let my co-workers know that I will not be working on a given day due to a national holiday.

However, just saying

> I will not be working Thursday, due to a national holiday

Feels a little awkward. Is this a correct phrase? Is there a better way to say it?

Comment: You might want to add a full stop at the end but otherwise that seems fine to me.

Comment: If you typically work in a building/office/manufacturing plant/etc. It is better to say "I will not be at work Thursday" or "I will be out of the office on Thursday." Using "I will not be working" puts too much focus on you not being productive, if that makes sense. It is, however, fine to use with friends/family outside of the company.

Comment: I think that's my issue - I work remotely, so 'Out of office' / 'Not at work' doesn't really make sense. But as you said, the current phrase almost sounds like I'm saying "I will be slacking"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am on holiday on Thursday.

No further explanation would normally be expected. You can of course expand on this with who to contact in your absence, when you'll be back, etc.

To specifically give an explanation while avoiding the awkward "holiday" repetition, you could simply say something along the lines of:

> It's a national holiday here on Thursday, and I will be on leave returning Friday.

Answer (score 2):

> I will be observing (name of Holiday) this Thursday. I hope to see
>   everyone Friday.

There is no single "correct" way to express what you want. I believe the above will accomplish what you wish.

Comment: This is good, but doesn't really work for me - I will, in fact not be observing the holiday in a religious sense - it's just a day off for me.